# Generalizng the inequality $x²+y²+z²+x+y+z ≥ 2(xy+yz+zx)$ for more than 3 variables

Tags: inequality

If $x,y, z > 0$ and $xyz=1$, the proof of
$x²+y²+z²+x+y+z ≥ 2(xy+yz+zx)$ 
 was already discussed in a previously submitted issue. 
For two positive numbers $x,y > 0$ and $xy =1$ 
above result can be reduced to the form of 
$x² + 1/x² ≥ x + 1/x$  
Now the challenge is how to generalise the first result for more than 3 variables.  
That is for n positive numbers, 
Let $a,b,c,d.... > 0$ and $abcd ..... =1$ 
$A + B ≥ 2C$  
where
$A = a²+b²+ ...$
$B = a+b+....$ and $C$ is the sum of products of $n-1$ terms . 
(when you consider n positive numbers$ x ,1/x > 0$ with $n -2$ ones  
$A + B ≥ 2C$ gives $x² + 1/x² ≥ x + 1/x$) 
Is there any possibility of proving the general result for n positive numbers by a combination of Schur's inequality for more than 3 variables and Muirhead's inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no: let $x_1, x_2,\ldots, x_n$ be the variables. Assuming you mean $C=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}x_i x_j$, then consider the case where all the variables are equal to $1$. Then $A+B=2n$, while $2C=2\binom{n}{2}=n^2-n$, which is larger for all $n\geq 4$

If you mean something like

$$C= x_1x_2 + x_2x_3 + x_3x_4+\cdots + x_nx_1$$

so that no variable appears more than twice in $C$, then you need to specify an order in which they appear.  It's not a well formulated question unless you assume something like

$$x_1\geq x_2\geq\cdots\geq x_n$$

Even then, take something like

$$x_1=x_2=x_3=20,\ x_4=1,\ x_5=\frac{1}{8000}$$

and you get that the inequality doesn't hold

Edit: For $C$ the $n-1$-th elementary symmetric polynomial i.e.
$$C=x_1x_2\ldots x_{n-1}+\cdots=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{x_n}$$

I think this still fails. Take $$x_1=x_2=x_3=20,\ x_4=\frac{1}{8000}$$
for $n=4$. Then the LHS is equal to 1260+something tiny, while the RHS is greater than 16,000

Comment: Perhaps $C$ is sum of all pairs $x_ix_j$

Comment: @Aidan - You are correct,thank you very much for mentioning the mistake , I have corrected.  C is sum of products of n-1 terms. Actually I described the issue taking that into consideration.

Comment: @Aqua - really sorry for the mistake, C is sum of products of all n - 1 terms.  If there are 4 numbers lets say  a,b,c,d then C is abc + bcd +cda +abd .

Comment: Is it ok to  use \sum₋1^n ( xᵢ ²  )  for sum of squares of n positive numbers that is to denote A , \sum₋1^n ( xᵢ  )  for sum of n positive numbers that is to denote B. Then what about C , I think there is a notation for that using Σ  cycle

Comment: I meant how to denote symmetrical sums using Σ  ?

Comment: @JanakaRodrigo To denote a symmetrically sum, I think the standard notation would be something like $\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{sym}f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. If you are really interested in generalising this, it is probably worthwhile looking into relations between elementary symmetric polynomials. Every symmetric polynomial can be written in terms of them, and you might be able to prove something using a method similar to the pqr approach from the previous question